# NoReverseMatch encountered when importing one Django template into another

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django project, I have a mini navbar that is common in ~30% of my templates. Instead of including it in my global `base.html`, I decided to take a different route.

I first wrote a separate view for this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def navbar(origin=None):
    if origin == '1':
        locations = get_approved_loc(withscores=True)
    else:
        locations = get_approved_loc()
    obj_count = get_all_obj_count()
    return render_to_string("mini_navbar.html",{'top_3_locs':locations[:3],\
        'other_cities':len(locations[3:]),'obj_count':obj_count})
```

I next added it in the templates it needed to be in via:

```
{% include "mini_navbar.html" with origin='1' %}
```

When I run this code, I get a `NoReverseMatch` error. It seems the view function `navbar` never runs. So the context variables it was sending in (e.g. `top_3_locs` or `other_cities` etc) are never populated. Hence `NoReverseMatch`.

What's wrong with this pattern, and what's the fix for it? An illustrative example would do the trick.

Comment: `include` doesn't call a view, it includes another template, the two snippets you've included aren't related

Comment: no need of view to include a template in another template just use include

Comment: the same thing you did earlier, make a template and include in base.html

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: so you're suggesting I populate the context variables from the respective templates I include the mini navbar in?

Comment: @Exprator: I used `{% extends "base.html" %}` there (i.e. inheritence). That's added globally. Could you give me an example that fits this particular scenario?

Comment: as you say you want to include the navbar in 30% of templates, so you can do one thing, in base.html keep a checking if yes then navbar will be shown else not, and from the views send a context with yes for those views where you will show navbar else dont send if you dont want to show

Comment: @Exprator: oh you mean like that. Sure, that's one way to do it. It's actually a moderately big project - so if I take this route, there's a ton of if-else I'd have to do in base.html. I was hoping to avoid that. The example given in the question is a simplification of the actual scenario.

Comment: yeah but thats not gonna happen, as you dont need tons of if-else, just one in base.html, if yes inlcude or dont, but make sure from each view you pass the same value, like yes or show and in base.html just check the value exist or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than including a template directly, you should write a custom template tag - specifically, an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) that renders the template with the custom context. The code that you have put in that separate view goes in that template tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an illustrative example of Daniel's suggestion:

I created an '[inclusion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)' template tag like so:

```
from django import template
from redis_modules import get_approved_loc, get_all_obj_coun

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag(file_name='mini_navbar.html')
def mini_navbar(origin=None):
    locations = get_approved_loc(withscores=True)
    obj_count = get_all_obj_count()
    return {'top_3_locs':locations[:3],'origin':origin,'other_cities':len(locations[3:]),'obj_count':obj_count}
```

Next I included this in the relevants templates like so:

```
{% load get_mini_navbar %} <!-- name of the module -->
```

And finally, I called it within the template like so:

```
{% mini_navbar origin %}
```

Where `origin` is the parameter passed into the tag.